pa11y-ci with nextjs won't pass in Github Actions CI
My pa11y-ci tests pass locally fine, but in Github Actions CI it fails to run (seems like it can't connect to `localhost:3000)
.pallyci.json:
{
  "defaults": {
    "timeout": 60000,
  },
  "urls": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "viewport": { "width": 320, "height": 480 },
      "actions": [
        "wait for element #main-content to be visible",
        "screen capture screenshots-output/mobile-main-view.png",
        "click element .usa-navbar button",
        "screen capture screenshots-output/mobile-expand-menu.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "actions": [
        "wait for element #main-content to be visible",
        "screen capture screenshots-output/desktop-main-view-home.png"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


package.json:
"scripts":{
...
    "test:pa11y": "pa11y-ci --config .pa11yci.json",
...
}


wait for frontend script is just a shell script that waits until localhost:3000 is available

Github actions workflow file ci-frontend-a11y.yml


name: pa11y tests

on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - frontend/**
      - .github/workflows/ci-frontend-a11y.yml

jobs:
  build:
    name: Pa11y-ci tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./frontend

    env:
      NODE_VERSION: 20
      LOCKFILE_PATH: ./frontend/package-lock.json
      PACKAGE_MANAGER: npm

    steps:
      - name: Checkout source
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache-dependency-path: ${{ env.LOCKFILE_PATH }}
          cache: ${{ env.PACKAGE_MANAGER }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Create screenshots directory
        run: mkdir -p screenshots-output

      - name: Build project
        run: npm run build

      - name: Start server and log output
        run: npm run start &

      - name: Wait for server to be ready
        run: |
          # Ensure the server wait script is executable
          chmod +x ./bin/wait-for-frontend.sh
          ./bin/wait-for-frontend.sh

      - name: Run pa11y-ci
        run: |
            npm run test:pa11y
            echo "pa11y-ci tests finished."


In CI it Failed to run
Run npm run test:pa11y
  npm run test:pa11y
  echo "pa11y-ci tests finished."
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    NODE_VERSION: 20
    LOCKFILE_PATH: ./frontend/package-lock.json
    PACKAGE_MANAGER: npm

> frontend@0.1.0 test:pa11y
> pa11y-ci --config .pa11yci.json

Running Pa11y on 10 URLs:
 > http://localhost:3000/ - Failed to run
pa11y-ci tests finished.


The answer was using --no-sandbox in the .pa11yci.json config file. I believe the chrome sandboxing is a security feature that isolates web pages to prevent malicious pages from affecting other pages - however it relis on system capabilities that might not be available or configured in shared or restricted infrastructure.  CI environments
{
  "defaults": {
    "timeout": 240000,
    "runners": ["axe"],
    "ignore": ["color-contrast"],
    "concurrency": 1,
    "chromeLaunchConfig": {
      "ignoreHTTPSErrors": true,
      "args": ["--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--no-sandbox"]
    }
  },
  "urls": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "viewport": { "width": 320, "height": 480 },
      "actions": [
        "wait for element #main-content to be visible",
        "screen capture screenshots-output/mobile-main-view.png",
        "click element .usa-navbar button",
        "screen capture screenshots-output/mobile-expand-menu.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "actions": [
        "wait for element #main-content to be visible",
        "screen capture screenshots-output/desktop-main-view-home.png"
      ]
    },
    ... (more URL)
  ]
}

